# Windows installer window pops up while executing msi in silent mode

Tags: windows-installer

Executing MsSqlCmdLnUtilsx64 in silent mode, but Windows installer message window pops up while installing. My command parameters are like this,
**"/qn /i "package.msi" /IACCEPTMSSQLCMDLNUTILSLICENSETERMS=YES"**. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: This pop up is the msiexec help pop up. It’s telling you it doesn’t like your command line. The /I <packageName> should come first. Move the /qn to after the packageName

Answer (score 0):

***Command Line***: There is a similar question here: [Installing sqlcmd in silent mode accepting EULA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160513/installing-sqlcmd-in-silent-mode-accepting-eula), but it might be for a different version of the tool. However, let's try with these command lines:

```
msiexec.exe /I "MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\MyLog.log" IACCEPTMSSQLCMDLNUTILSLICENSETERMS=YES
```

or

```
msiexec.exe /i "MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi" /passive IACCEPTMSSQLCMDLNUTILSLICENSETERMS=YES
```

---

***Some Further Links***:

- **[How to make better use of MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458857/how-to-make-better-use-of-msi-files/1055861#1055861)** (on setting msiexec.exe parameters and more)
- [Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 14.0 for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591)
- [Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433)