# MSI Installer only pulling up prompt from command line; not running

Tags: windows-installer, command-prompt

I've seen multiple questions online about this exact thing:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/874022-msiexec-just-returns-a-pop-up

[Windows installer window pops up while executing msi in silent mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233550/windows-installer-window-pops-up-while-executing-msi-in-silent-mode)

My question is the same as in these forums. When I try to run an MSI through a command line, all it does is pull up a prompt giving me a list of parameters. The other questions recommended that I type the command out myself and not copy it because the quotes might not actually be quotes and to try moving the pieces of my command around because it is in the wrong order. Here is my command:

START /WAIT msiexec.exe /i "\hostname\Departments\Technologies\Installs\Bluebeam Revu\MSIBluebeamRevu20.2.30x64\Bluebeam Revu x64 20.msi" BB_SERIALNUMBER [1623974] BB_PRODUCTKEY [56UI4-66FDZJ5]

I also tried adding transforms:

START /WAIT msiexec.exe /i "\hostname\Departments\Technologies\Installs\Bluebeam Revu\MSIBluebeamRevu20.2.30x64\Bluebeam Revu x64 20.msi" TRANSFORMS="\hostname\Departments\Technologies\Installs\Bluebeam Revu\20.0.20 Standard-Extreme\MSIBluebeamRevu20.2.30x64\Bluebeam Revu x64 20.msi" BB_SERIALNUMBER [1623974] BB_PRODUCTKEY [56UI4-66FDZJ5]

I have tried looking in task managers command line tab to view what command was being run and it exactly what I have above

[image: What happens when I run it]

Here is the task manager and what it says it ran from
[image: Task Manager]

I am trying to push this out to my active directory through a software called PDQ so I need this command line to work. Currently I am only testing it locally on my computer.

Comment: Why do you use single slash for the start of the path? Try using double for UNC paths: //Servername/Path

Comment: @SteinÅsmul not sure why it did that when I copied it over but if you look at the first photo I am using \\ before the path

Comment: OK, set equal sign for your properties: BB_SERIALNUMBER=[1623974] for a start. The msiexec.exe command line is complex and picky.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul that worked, but now I'm getting the same error I had before where it tells me that the installation package could not be opened. I am going to contact the vendor of the package. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What vendor package is it? You can have a look at itninja.com Software Tips library: https://www.itninja.com/software-library - sample page for Adobe: https://www.itninja.com/software-library/company/adobe

Comment: When you pate the UNC path (minus the msi name) into Start => Run  (hold Windows key down and press R) - does the folder open?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul yes, the folder opens and if I add the msi file at the end it opens the correct UI as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234667/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-nick).